# Setting cucumber tag via System property

Tags: tags, cucumber, bdd

My entire feature stack is divided into @sanity(10 scenarios) and @smoke(2 scenarios) and whole stack is considered as @regression (no tag required, and total scenarios: 37). My question is how can I pass tag value via command line. Please note this is a cucumber-testng project
Below is how my runner file looks:
[image]

Please note, I have tried below command line commands but it still runs @smoke and @sanity both cases (meaning 12 scenarios)

./gradlew -i test -Denv=release -D"cucumber.options=--tags @sanity" ---> It runs 12 scenarios

./gradlew -i test -Denv=release -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@smoke"---> It runs 12 scenarios

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the tests from command line only, try removing the `tags=@sanity or @smoke` from your runner file first and then try `....-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@smoke"` from the command line again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hhs but doing that also, it still doesnt run the annotated scenarios but instead runs the entire stack

Comment: @sandeepsenapati Hmm, I am wondering if the gradle build can access the JVM params. Can you add this to your build.gradle file and retry.

test { 
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.getProperty("cucumber.options")
}

Answer (score 0):

So this worked. Apparently I had missed adding below line in my build.gradle file
[image]

Comment: Consider removing the image and putting the solution in as text.